# Amazon EC2 Windows EBS and bandwidth charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to know how Amazon EC2 charge for EBS and the bandwidth for Windows and I want to know the how many Tomcat web servers and MySQL servers can be placed in one EC2 server.

Answer (score 1):

Pricing references:

- [Amazon EC2 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)
- [Amazon EBS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/)

**Amazon EBS (Elastic Block Store)** is priced according to the size of the volume and the type of volume. See the above pricing links for more details. Note that the amount is charged based on **provisioned** storage, which means the full disk size is charged rather than just the proportion of the volume that is used.

There is no specific charge for **bandwidth for Amazon EC2 instances**, however traffic that is leaving a region and going to the Internet (from any service, including EC2) is charged for **Data Transfer**. For details, see the ***Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet*** section of the [Amazon EC2 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) page.

Also there is a **restriction on the network bandwidth assigned to any Amazon EC2 instance**. Basically, larger instances have more bandwidth. See the ***Networking Performance*** column on the [Instance Types Matrix](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-type-matrix). While no specific bandwidths are given, relative measures are provided (eg "Low to Moderate", "High"). Some large instance types (eg `m4.10xlarge`) have *10 Gigabit* bandwidth between instances (but not necessarily out to the Internet).

**The number of Tomcat web servers and MySQL servers that can be placed in one EC2 server** is totally dependent upon your particular situation and the Instance Type chosen. For example, a heavily-used application and database will require more resources. Experimentation and performance testing would assist in making this decision.

Also, if you wish to run **MySQL**, you might consider using [Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) (Relational Database Service) to provision a fully-managed database instead of installing and maintaining one on your own EC2 instance.